# How to automatically fit the camera to objects in the view?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, 3d-view, camera

I'm using blender to render avatar and avatar accessories on a website, however there is a problem, when a hat, or accessory is made a bit large, the it doesn't fit in the viewport, is there anyway to make the viewport expand or move backwards to fit the entire object automatically with python?

[image]

Comment: I usually get a camera, press 0 on the numpad to view from it, press N and then under View i select "Lock camera to View" i then select my object(s) i wish to zoom in on and press the Dot/period key.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an operator to do *exactly* this. it can be called from Python or accessed from a menu.

- Select the objects you wish to put in the camera view.
- View -> Align View -> Align Active Camera to Selected.

Or run the operator: `bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()`

eg:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

# Select objects that will be rendered
for obj in context.scene.objects:
    obj.select_set(False)
for obj in context.visible_objects:
    if not (obj.hide_get() or obj.hide_render):
        obj.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()
```

There is also an object method to place a camera given input coordinates: [`Object.camera_fit_coords()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.camera_fit_coords)

---

If you want a margin around the objects, you could temporarily reduce the cameras view angle, then restore it afterwards, or simply move the camera back along its Z axis.

Comment: Hey, I've tried your scripts, and the camera_to_view_selected function just returns "{'CANCELLED'}". Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

I am not at all a programmer, but have you looked into the *View All* operator?

```
bpy.ops.view3d.view_all()
```

or perhaps the View Selected if the one above doesn't work well for you

```
bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected()
```

You can find documentation here https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html