# Snap camera boundaries to object

Tags: rendering, camera

Is there a method to snap the camera boundaries to the object I need to render? I tried turning the snap magnet on to see if there is a way those boundaries might work. The only way I do it, is by manually zooming in as much possible to adjust the boundaries around my object, which is a little bit tedious,and some pixels might not be perfect within the boundaries.

thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but perhaps it will help. The following works only if your object dimensions relatively match the resolution (e.g. I created a cube of size [1.92m, 2m, 1.08m] for resolution of 1920:1080)

1. Press `Num 1` to enter viewport front view
2. Press `Ctrl + Alt + Num0` to apply the view to camera and enter camera view.
3. Select the object you want to focus on
4. In the search bar enter `Camera Fit Frame to Selected`

Before and after:

[image]

Source: [How to automatically fit the camera to objects in the view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51563/how-to-automatically-fit-the-camera-to-objects-in-the-view)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what If I needed the cube to be 700 X 500px, how would the camera fit to frame? That would mean I'd have to convert the cube metres into pixels or vice versa. Seems a little bit confusing.

Comment: It's not about metres but rather ratio. If you needed a 700 X 500px render you would set you render resolution to 700:500 and set the cube proportions to match the width/height ratio of 700/500 = 1.4/1. It can be 7m x 5m or 0.7m x 0.5m or even 1.4m x 1m. You can set the ratio through dimensions or scale. Once again, not perfect, but better than manually editing the boundaries